# AES Encryption in Python - different results when using pycryptodome and cryptography

Tags: python, cryptography

We're moving away from `pycryptodome` to `cryptography` due to security considerations. 
When encoding the same plain-text string with pycryptodome I get a different cypher text than cryptography, consider the following code:

Pycryptodome:

```py
    def aes_encrypt(self, plain_text):
        try:
            plain_text_with_padding = self._aes_pad(plain_text).encode("utf-8")
            cipher = AES.new(self.aes_secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.aes_iv)

            msg = cipher.encrypt(plain_text_with_padding)

            return msg.encode("hex")
        except Exception as e:
            raise AesError(e.message)
```

Cryptography:

```py
    def aes_encrypt(self, plain_text):
        try:
            plain_text_with_padding = self._aes_pad(plain_text)
            encryptor = Cipher(
                algorithm=algorithms.AES(self.aes_secret_key),
                mode=modes.CBC(self.aes_iv),
                backend=default_backend(),

            ).encryptor()

            msg = encryptor.update(plain_text_with_padding) + encryptor.finalize()

            return msg.encode("hex")
        except Exception as e:
            raise AesError(e.message)

    @staticmethod
    def _aes_pad(s):
        padding_length = AES.block_size - (len(s) % AES.block_size)
        return s + padding_length * chr(padding_length)
```

The test code:

```py
    def setUp(self):
        secret_manager = Mock()
        secret_manager.get_secret.return_value = {
            "hmac_secret_key": "secret",
            "aes_secret_key": "fbc1f4bf4c826fc41d27905bc3eb8cbb",
            "aes_iv": "J3wmcjV0Vzd9Jw=="
        }
        self.crypto_utils = CryptoUtils(secret_manager)

    def test_aes_encrypt(self):
        asset_id = "123456"

        encrypted_asset_id = self.crypto_utils.aes_encrypt(asset_id)

        self.assertEqual(
            "926fbb0584c6e357157709e723b0e0d2",
            encrypted_asset_id
        )
```

The same test code **pass** using `pycryptodome` but generate much longer cipher text when using `cryptography`.

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: `msg = encryptor.update(plain_text_with_padding) + encryptor.finalize()` should be `msg = encryptor.finalize()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, both libs produce the expected result, using the parts of code you provided. Make sure that you use the same values for both methods, and that those values are not modified by other class methods.

Comment: @t.m.adam I'm currently working on mac os with Python 2.7.16 in virtualenv. When running the same code on a Windows machine available to me I get the expected **correct** results, thanks for that. However - it doesn't explain why I get incorrect results on my Mac. Additionally, when this code is executed as part of our CI/CD pipeline (CircleCI) it produces the same (incorrect) results.

Comment: That's interesting. Your code works correctly on my local machine - Windows with Python 2.7 (and Python 3.7 with some minor adjustments) and on Repl.it - Linux2 with Python 2.7 ([link](https://repl.it/@tasos_py/so)) So it seems the problem is specific to Cryptography on MAC. Maybe you've found a bug?

Comment: Just posted an issue in the project GitHub page https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be the AES block size - in the previous implementation (`Pycryptodome`) it’s given in `bytes` while in the new lib (`cryptography`) it’s given in `bits`.

When running the same code with the following changes using `cryptography` it produces the expected results:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def _aes_pad(s):
        block_size_bytes = AES.block_size / 8
        padding_length = block_size_bytes - (len(s) % block_size_bytes)
        return s + padding_length * chr(padding_length)
```

Comment: Please add this as the selected answer